# How to generate data set for training CNN in dlib using c++, such as MNIST data set format?

Tags: c++, dlib

MNIST TRAINING SET LABEL FILE (train-labels-idx1-ubyte) has the following format:

```
[offset] [type]          [value]          [description]
0000     32 bit integer  0x00000801(2049) magic number (MSB first)
0004     32 bit integer  60000            number of items
0008     unsigned byte   ??               label
0009     unsigned byte   ??               label
........
xxxx     unsigned byte   ??               label
```

The labels values are 0 to 9. How can I create such format for using my own training data set using C++ not python.

Comment: Please format your data set so that it is readable to others. You can use ``` for code block.

Comment: Open `std::ofstream` in the binary mode and output data into in with `write`.